# Converting Gallery3 .htaccess mod_rewrite code to IIS URL Rewrite in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a website on which i have installed Gallery3. The url is

```
 http://techblog.lalsofttech.com/gallery/
```

But when i open the "test album", in the url there is index.php

```
http://techblog.lalsofttech.com/gallery/index.php/test
```

Now what i want is to remove the index.php from the url and want the url to look like this

```
 http://techblog.lalsofttech.com/gallery/test
```

Since my shared server space is a windows platform with IIS 7, i cant use the .htaccess file.
Since my server got Microsoft URL Rewrite module installed i need to write the rewrite rule in web.config file.

This is the code for hiding the index.php in the .htaccess file

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /gallery
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [QSA,PT,L]
  RewriteRule ^$ index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [QSA,PT,L]
  RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) $1 [QSA,R,L]
 </IfModule>
```

I tried to convert this by installing the Microsoft URL Rewrite module in my localhost.

Except the "RewriteBase /gallery" all the other codes get converted ."RewriteBase /gallery is not converted because it is not supported by IIS" is the error message i got.
And this is the converted code.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?kohana_uri={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?kohana_uri={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^index.php/(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

But it seems this code is not working as the index.php is still there. The ISS URL Rewrite Module is working since another rule "Enforce canonical hostname" which i added in the web.config is working properly.

This is my complete web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Enforce canonical hostname" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.moviega\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.moviega.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?kohana_uri={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?kohana_uri={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^index.php/(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So where is the problem??. What should be done to remove the index.php from the url??
Please help me sort this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have to do with where<sup>1</sup> you place this Web.config file.  As long as it is in the `http://www.MovieGa.com/gallery/` subdirectory, I think it should work...!

**EDIT:**
In response to your second question, here is probably why that error is happening:

It has to do with this part:

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?kohana_uri={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

With *.htaccess,* I think this works fine.  But with *Web.config*, it gives you that error because<sup>2</sup> it's trying to find capture groups in regex while there are none in this particular `<match url="^$">` section.  If you remove that `?kohana_uri={R:1}` part from the `url=""`, does it work?

Reference:

<sup>1</sup> http://forums.iis.net/t/1162232.aspx (Anil Ruia's comment)

<sup>2</sup> http://forums.iis.net/t/1150904.aspx (ruslany's second comment)

Comment: That i have already done, which i have posted over here http://forums.iis.net/t/1186418.aspx But when ever i access my site like http://www.MovieGa.com/gallery/ this, there comes another error  "HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
The expression "index.php?kohana_uri={R:1}" cannot be expanded.". But if i call the page with index.php in the url everything works fine. You can see the error i am mentioning here http://techblog.lalsofttech.com/Gallery/

Comment: I've updated my answer above; does taking out `?kohana_uri={R:1}` from the "Imported Rule 2" work for you?

Comment: Thanks that solved that error 500 issue..But again there is one issue in this page http://techblog.lalsofttech.com/Gallery Here if we move the move over any of the albums or links, you can see the index.php will be there,which is not supposed to be there.. Like this http://techblog.lalsofttech.com/Gallery/index.php/test .If we click that, in the next page url that index.php wont be there,that's ok..but showing index.php in all those links in the home page is not good and is not supposed to be there

Comment: Though not fully solved,since you have taken the effort to help me out,i am giving the +50 bounty for your. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks!  As for that last question... I was looking at the `application/config/config.php` file, and I wonder if changing this variable would take away the `index.php` from links:
`$config["index_page"] = isset($_GET["kohana_uri"]) ? "" : "index.php";`  It's on line 57 on my version of Gallery 3.

Comment: I have already nailed it..just changed url="^$" to url="^()$" so now the "Imported Rule 2" looks like this  <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^()$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?kohana_uri={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
Thanks for the help again :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i will make things clear here,for those who are  installing gallery 3 in Windows Server with IIS7
and are trying to get rid of the index.php file from the url.

1st : Keep your web.config file with the rewrite rules in the directory where you are installing gallery and not the root of your website

2nd : The rewrite rules of the web.config file that you are placing inside the gallery folder should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>

<rewrite>
 <rules>
   <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
     <conditions>
       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?kohana_uri={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
   </rule>
   <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^()$" ignoreCase="false" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?kohana_uri={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
   </rule>
   <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^index.php/(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
     <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
   </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>

</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope this will be useful for others who are facing the same problems like the one i encountered..